# vue: Dynamically inject property data into <component />

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a layout component which dynamically creates given components from a parent in either one or the other column. In the layout component I'm using the  directive to create the children components. That works, however I'm having a hard time to get the data into the components themselves (they have different sets of properties).

Therefore:

## How to inject property data into the < component :is="componentFromParent" / > directive?

I've got something to work, but it's pretty messy. I could do it via a "genericProps" property which contains all the data. Then forcing the children to update and they, via `updated()`, use `Object.assign(this, 'props', this.genericProps)` to unpack the `genericProps` and overwrite it's `$props`.

It feels pretty much as if I'm working against some princiles of vue.js here. When debugging the `this.$options.components` of the layout component are filled, however all these components don't have any `propsData` assigned. But directly using `Object.assign()` on the `this.$options.components` doesn't work, as it seems the layout component as the actually instances of these components as it's `this.$childrend`.

Also I've tried looping through the `this.$childrend` and assigning the `propsData` of the `this.$options.components` but there would have to be a key to match the components with it's correct child and at that point the childrend don't have any properties filled.

Code snippets to illustrate the (ugly) example which kinda works:

## Parent Template

```
<template>
  <two-column-layout :firstColumn="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp ? firstColumn : singleColumn"
                      :secondColumn="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp ? secondColumn : []"
                      />
</template>
```

## Parent Code

This code is called via mounted() or via watch when the async call from the API is finished.

```
  createMetadataContent() {

    let currentContent = this.currentMetadataContent;
    const components = this.$options.components;

    currentContent = this.mixinMethods_enhanceMetadataEntry(currentContent, this.cardBGImages);

    if (currentContent && currentContent.title !== undefined) {

      this.body = metaDataFactory.createBody(currentContent);
      this.$set(components.MetadataBody, 'genericProps', this.body);

      this.citation = metaDataFactory.createCitation(currentContent);
      this.$set(components.MetadataCitation, 'genericProps', this.citation);
      // a few more components and data here


      this.firstColumn = [
        components.MetadataBody,
        // a few more components here
      ];

      this.secondColumn = [
        components.MetadataCitation,
        // a few more components here
      ];

      this.singleColumn = [
        components.MetadataBody,
        components.MetadataCitation,
        // a few more components here
      ];

      this.$forceUpdate();
    }
  }
```

## TwoColumnLayout Template

```
<template>          
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex>

      <v-layout column>
        <v-flex mb-2
                v-for="(entry, index) in firstColumn"
                :key="`left_${index}`"
                >
          <component :is="entry"
                      :genericProps="entry.genericProps"
                      />
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex v-if="secondColumn" >
      <v-layout column>
        <v-flex mb-2
                v-for="(entry, index) in secondColumn"
                :key="`right_${index}`"
                >
          <component :is="entry"
                      :genericProps="entry.genericProps"
                      />
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

## TwoColumnLayout Code

```
updated() {
  this.$children.forEach((child) => {
    child.$forceUpdate();
  });
},
```

## Child Code

```
  props: {
    genericProps: Object,
    id: String,
    citationText: String,
    citationXmlLink: String,
    ciationIsoXmlLink: String,
    ciationGCMDXmlLink: String,
    fixedHeight: Boolean,
    showPlaceholder: Boolean,
  },
  updated: function updated() {
    if (this.genericProps) {
      Object.assign(this, 'props', this.genericProps);
    }
  },
```

Comment: Sounds like a logistical problem, have a look at `slots` : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it via slot but I've still needed to use `forceUpdate()` in the LayoutComponent...
However with the genericProps it's good enough for my case.

## Parent Template

```
  <template v-slot:leftColumn >

    <div v-for="(entry, index) in firstColumn" :key="`left_${index}`" >

      <component :is="entry" :genericProps="entry.genericProps" />
    </div>
  </template>

  <template v-slot:rightColumn>

    <div v-for="(entry, index) in secondColumn" :key="`right_${index}`" >

      <component :is="entry" :genericProps="entry.genericProps" />
    </div>
  </template>
```

## Parent Code

This code is called via `mounted()` or via watch when the async call from the API is finished.

```
  createMetadataContent() {

    let currentContent = this.currentMetadataContent;
    const components = this.$options.components;

    currentContent = this.mixinMethods_enhanceMetadataEntry(currentContent, this.cardBGImages);

    if (currentContent && currentContent.title !== undefined) {

      this.body = metaDataFactory.createBody(currentContent);
      this.$set(components.MetadataBody, 'genericProps', this.body);

      this.citation = metaDataFactory.createCitation(currentContent);
      this.$set(components.MetadataCitation, 'genericProps', this.citation);
      // a few more components and data here


      this.firstColumn = [
        components.MetadataBody,
        // a few more components here
      ];

      this.secondColumn = [
        components.MetadataCitation,
        // a few more components here
      ];

      this.singleColumn = [
        components.MetadataBody,
        components.MetadataCitation,
        // a few more components here
      ];

      this.$forceUpdate();
    }
  }
```

## TwoColumnLayout Template

```
    <v-flex v-bind="firstColWidth" >

      <v-layout column>

        <slot name="leftColumn" />

      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>


    <v-flex v-if="secondColumn" v-bind="secondColWidth" >

      <v-layout column>

        <slot name="rightColumn" />

      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
```

## TwoColumnLayout Code

```
updated() {
  this.$children.forEach((child) => {
    child.$forceUpdate();
  });
},
```

## Child Code

All child components have the genericProps object which is accessed via mixin method

```
    props: {
      genericProps: Object,
    },
    computed: {
      title() {
        return this.mixinMethods_getGenericProp('title');
      },
      id() {
        return this.mixinMethods_getGenericProp('id');
      },
      description() {
        return this.mixinMethods_getGenericProp('description');
      },
    }
```

## Mixin method

```
    mixinMethods_getGenericProp(propName) {
      return this.genericProps[propName] ? this.genericProps[propName] : null;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar situation where I had a dynamic `<compnonent :is="currentComponent">` and solved it by storing a 'childPayload'-attribute to my data and passed it as prop to the children. Whenever my payload changed, it got refreshed in the children.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="btn btn-primary" @click="changePayload">Change Payload</div>
        <component :is="isWhat" :payload="payload"></component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Test",
        data() {
            return {
                isWhat: 'div',
                payload: { any: 'data', you: 'want', to: 'pass'}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changePayload() { // any method or api call can change the data
                this.payload = { some: 'changed', data: 'here' }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I understand your example, but I'm fighting with the problem of multiple components with different payloads.